# Why is VIsual Studio saying this code behind for my homepage.master.vb is missing an end tag?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio says this line is missing an end tag, but I've googled and googled, and cannot figure out what to put there.  This is my code behind for my homepage.master.vb:

```
Imports Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes

Partial Public Class Homepage

Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _
        Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].(SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
        RequestLanguageChange(Me.Request.QueryString("lang"))
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub RequestLanguageChange(ByVal culture As String)
    'store requested language as new culture in the session
    Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) = culture

    'reload last requested page with new culture
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path)
   End Sub
 End Class
```

The line that says:

```
   Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].(SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Is the line that's giving me all the trouble.  It's saying that an end tag is missing, or something.  Consequently, it's not working in conjunction with my classes -- BasePage.vb, Culture.vb, and Global.vb, and the page won't display.   The page is intended to give me URLs like clients.aspx?lang=FR.

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra parenthesis. Try `Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE)` or `Session([Global].(SESSION_KEY_CULTURE))`.

Comment: Thanks for replaying John.  I tried both of your solutions, and they're still underlined in Visual Studio, saying "End of Statement Expected"!  How strange!  I cannot figure this one out ...

Comment: At at the left side of the statement, it says "property access must assign to the property or use its value".   I'm not sure if this is an issue with one of the 3 classes I made:  Basepage.vb, culture.vb, and global.vb, all in my App_Code folder, but VS isn't recommending any fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no gap in the lines below...

```
 If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _
        Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].(SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Seems like you have one...

```
 If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _
        Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].(SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```